# Evaluate the following integral : $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}(x+1)} dx$

Tags: calculus

I am unsure how to do this. I have been told that I must separate it into 2 limits since it is discontinuous at 0 and infinity. Could anyone help?

Update: I integrated by substitution by setting $u= \sqrt{x}$ and this was equal to $arctan{x}$. It is just the limits which I am unsure of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $I = \int_{0}^1 + \int_{1}^\infty$. For the first one, put $u = \sqrt{x}$, can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would you be able to explain why we use 1 as a lower and upper bound here please?

Comment: @E-m10: I used it because of the $x=0$ appears at the denominator and I don't want to deal with "double inproper" integral at the same time. It's just a routine habit.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @E-m10: Glad you liked my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Use the substitution $\;t=\sqrt x$, $\:\mathrm dx=2t\,\mathrm dt$.

The integral becomes
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{2t\,\mathrm dt}{2t(t^2+1)}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm dt}{t^2+1},$$
which shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

To find the indefinite integral, make the substitution $u=\sqrt x$, and the integrand is reduced to a nicer one.

About splitting it up, there's no need to split up the integral once you've performed the substitution as the new integral has only one limit that makes it improper.